# (m => m.Email) meaning (ASP.NET) and how to get a user's username

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am brand new to web development. What little experience I have is in C# Unity and Java. The code below was taken from the screen followed by the Google authentication/login screen. I am trying to set the user's Google name to the username on the website. I was wondering if someone could help me out and maybe explain what (m => m.Email) means.

Thank you so much!

```
@model Start.Models.ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLoginConfirmation", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })) {

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: In this scenario, the `=>` denotes a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the slightly more technical explanation. The `=>` operator denotes a lambda, which can be thought of as a function that returns its value in place. The stuff on the left side (`m`) is the parameter(s) to the "function", and the stuff on the right side is what will be returned from the "function". Given that, `m => m.Email` means, essentially, "return the `Email` property of what I pass in here".

However, when it comes to things like HtmlHelpers, what you're passing as the first parameter there is actually `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`, so let's unwrap that. `Func<TModel, TProperty>` is the actual type of that lambda we just talked about. `Func` is a generic type, with two (or more) type parameters. Here, the first type parameter is `TModel`, and corresponds to the type of the "left side" of the lamda, i.e. the type of the thing we're passing in. The `TProperty` type parameter is the type of the "right side" of the lambda, i.e. the thing we're returning.

`Expression` is a wrapper applied to things like `Func`, and builds what's called an "expression tree" out of the lambda. This expression tree, among other things, allows the inspection of what's inside that lambda, so you can determine things like the name of the property that's being returned. The HtmlHelpers, then, use this information to do things like generating `id` and `name` attributes, which obviously need to match the property name. This is actually an important thing to recognize as a lot of new developers get confused and think they can pass in just about anything to an HtmlHelper as the expression. That's not the case, because you're not dealing with a value, but rather an *expression representing a value*. For example, the following would not work at all:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email.ToLower())
```

Because it's not a valid expression, even though it works for the purpose of the lambda.

Answer (score 3):

in the code `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)` the variable `m` represents the current model, which is set at the top of the file as `Start.Models.ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel`.

`m => m.Email` means "get the `Email` property from this model".  If you were to look at the model (in Visual Studio put your mouse cursor on `ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel` and press <kbd>F12</kbd>) you will most likely see that there is an `Email` property on it.

So `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)` creates the HTML needed to show a textbox for the email address of the current model.

In the end it will probably generate some HTML that looks like this:

```
<input type="text" value="bob@example.com" id="some-generated-id-here" />
```

This is using the MVC Razor syntax, which you might want to do some reading up on.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor
- http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/razor-syntax

Comment: I would add that `TextBoxFor` then generates HTML, and also uses data annotation attributes on the Email property of the model class that might effect the HTML generation.   He might also be curious to understand that `m => m.Email` is using a C# language feature called lambda expression, but that is somewhat advanced concept and usually you don't think about it in CSHTML and rather just follow the pattern of it's usage.